# floating a list of divs of variable height in 3 column format

Tags: css, css-float

I have a list of product divs containing two more divs each displayed vertically within - top one containing an image and bottom one text. The text is variable in size so the outer divs size also is variable. These outer divs float left and go 3 to a row until a div with long text happens then the next row starts immediately after that column, leaving a gap.

So if I have a row where the 2nd div has 3 lines of text to the other two's 1, the 4th div will start not in the first position on the next line but in the 3rd.

Here is an image demonstrating what I see now vs a second what I would like to do:

[image: current]

And what I'm aiming to do

[image: ideal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use float. Take a look at this fiddle:

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
.block {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: -3px;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a row for the `div` elements, this will produce the layout you need! I have also provided a CSS only solution where the class `clearfix` will do the same thing as `row` class!

**CSS3:**

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
}
.box{
  background-color:grey;
  float:left;
  margin:3px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box" style="height:200px;">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

.box{
  background-color:grey;
  float:left;
  margin:3px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box" style="height:200px;">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's very clear. I actually don't have a 'row' div layer as the number of columns in each would depend on the total width available, ie it's 3 on mobile but more on desktop. Is it possible to do this 'clearfix' without the additional row layer?

Comment: @user1561108 There is an awesome library called `Bootstrap` which can do all that you say with ease, lowering your dev time! you can please checkout a video series on bootstrap, I'd recommend [Derek Banas Bootstrap tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTLRdrRQyN4), it will really help you!!!!

Comment: I have used bootstrap before, but what exactly in terms of css would enable me to forgo the extra div layer to get what you have posted above?

Comment: @user1561108 You need to use `max-height` and `min-height` to make all the div's the same height, followed by vertical centering the internal contents of the `div`, as far as I know all the `DIV`s need to be the same height, please let me also know if you find some other solution!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="box">img</div>
<div class="box">img</div>
<div class="box">img</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="box">txt</div>
<div class="box">txt</div>
<div class="box">txt</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container{
background:red;
display:flex;
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin:0% auto;
padding:1% 0;
}
.box{
min-width:100px;
height:auto;
padding:1%;
margin:0 1%;
flex-grow:1;
background:green;
}
```

Also, Please chech whether you have cleared all floats

Please see [Using CSS Flexible Boxes MDNweb docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)